# Анимация увеличения для UserControl wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, usercontrol

Как сделать так, чтобы при наведении мыши на UserControl, он увеличивался? Причём относительно текущих размеров?

Comment: что значит "относительно текущих размеров"?

Comment: UserControl заполняет всё пространство, т.е. я не прописываю ему жёсткие размеры, и поэтому они устанавливаются автоматически.

Comment: Я думаю, тут можно анимировать отступы тогда (`Margin`), а контент внутри сделать подстраиваемым через `Viewbox`, ну либо играться со `ScaleTransform`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Предположим, у нас есть такая разметка:

```xml
<Grid Background="Silver" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="300" Height="150">
    <Border Background="#FF1D1D1D" >
        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="45" Text="Привет мир!" Foreground="White"/>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

Она простая, лишь `Grid` расположенный по центру с установленным цветом, который содержит `Border` у которого также есть свой цвет, ну и сам он содержит простой `TextBlock`, расположенный также по центру и с "большим" размером шрифта. Наша задача `Border` сделать чуть меньше и анимировать его при событии мыши.

#### Масштабирование

За всякие манипуляции с пропорциями, в XAML отвечает `RenderTransform`, а именно масштаб, это `ScaleTransform`. Давайте применим это к разметке выше:

```xml
<Grid Background="Silver" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="300" Height="150">
    <Border Background="#FF1D1D1D" >
        <Border.RenderTransform>
            <ScaleTransform ScaleX=".5" ScaleY=".5"/>
        </Border.RenderTransform>
        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="45" Text="Привет мир!" Foreground="White"/>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

Результатом у нас будет такое:

[image: Scale 1]

Как видим, внутренний `Border` изменил свои пропорции, но он не по центру. Чтобы это исправить, нам надо сдвинуть центральную точку, а за это отвечает свойство `RenderTransformOrigin`, зададим нашему `Border`' это свойство со значением `0.5 0.5` и увидим то, что нам надо:

[image: Scale 2]

#### Триггеры

Теперь давайте разберемся как нам обработать "наведение мыши" на нужный объект в XAML.
А тут все просто, для взаимодействия с событиями, отлов изменений свойств и так далее, для всего этого существую **триггеры**, их всего 4:

| Название | Описание |
| --- | --- |
| `Trigger` (триггер свойств) | Самый простой триггер, который следит за значением свойства и если оно соответствует заданному, то выполняет указанное действие. |
| `DataTrigger` (триггер данных) | Его цель аналогична предыдущему, но разница в том, что он поддерживает привязки и мы можем отслеживать тем самым свойства из ViewModel слоя. |
| `MultiTrigger` (Мультитриггер) | Позволяет отслеживать сразу несколько свойств при помощи коллекции `Conditions`. |
| `EventTrigger` (триггер событий) | А он уже следит за тем, какое событие выдал наш элемент. Допустим клик кнопки, либо наведение мыши. |

Исходя из этого вы можете составить любое условие, по которому контрол изменит цвет, запустит анимацию или что-либо еще. В вашей задачи фигурирует "при наведении мыши", а значит нам нужен `EventTrigger`. Давайте допишем пример выше, добавив в него триггер:

```xml
<Grid Background="Silver" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="300" Height="150">
    <Border Background="#FF1D1D1D" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5 0.5" >
        <Border.RenderTransform>
            <ScaleTransform ScaleX=".5" ScaleY=".5"/>
        </Border.RenderTransform>
        <Border.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter" >

            </EventTrigger>
        </Border.Triggers>
        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="45" Text="Привет мир!" Foreground="White"/>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

Здесь в качестве события мы берем `MouseEnter` - это событие происходит тогда, когда мы наводим мышью на объект.

#### Анимация

Наша задача сейчас, это анимировать значения у `ScaleTransform`, а именно `ScaleX` и `ScaleY`, делается это примерно так:

```xml
<BeginStoryboard>
    <Storyboard>
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleX" To="1" Duration="0:0:.4">
            <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                <QuarticEase />
            </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
        </DoubleAnimation>
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleY" To="1" Duration="0:0:.4" >
            <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                <QuarticEase />
            </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
        </DoubleAnimation>
    </Storyboard>
</BeginStoryboard>
```

Поясняю:

- Сначала мы создаем базовый элемент `BeginStoryboard`, который будет отвечать за анимацию
- Далее мы создаем саму анимацию при помощи `Storyboard`. Если дословно перевести, то думаю будет ясно, что это "раскадровка".
- Внутри мы можем хоть покадрово анимировать все, что нам необходимо, но в WPF есть ряд готовых объектов, которые отлично анимируют нужные свойства. Для нужных нам свойство нужна анимация `DoubleAnimation` (ибо значения типа `double`). У нее мы задаем:

  - `Storyboard.TargetProperty` - цель анимации (наше свойство `ScaleX` или `ScaleY`)
  - `To` - до какого значение будет плавно идти анимация.
  - `From` - мы тут не ставим, ибо нам нужна анимация "от текущего до нужного", а если поставим, то будет "от заданного до нужного", что приведет к рывкам анимации.
  - `Duration` - как долго эта анимация должна идти.
  - Также тут стоит `EasingFunction` - они позволяют анимацию сделать более плавно, например в начале ускорить, а в конце плавно замедлить. Почитать про них можете например [тут](https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/16.5.php).

Также я думаю вы заметили, что тут анимируется сразу два свойства, `Storyboard` как я уже говорил выше, это набор кадров и в нем вы можете без проблем задать их несколько!

Теперь давайте соединим это все и посмотрим на результат:

```xml
<Grid Background="Silver" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="300" Height="150">
    <Border Background="#FF1D1D1D" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5 0.5" >
        <Border.RenderTransform>
            <ScaleTransform ScaleX=".5" ScaleY=".5"/>
        </Border.RenderTransform>
        <Border.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter" >
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleX" To="1" Duration="0:0:.4">
                            <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                <QuarticEase />
                            </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                        </DoubleAnimation>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleY" To="1" Duration="0:0:.4" >
                            <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                <QuarticEase />
                            </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                        </DoubleAnimation>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Border.Triggers>
        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="45" Text="Привет мир!" Foreground="White"/>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

[image: Animation Result]

Собственно, вот и готовая анимация масштабирования, осталось только сделать тоже самое, но в обратную сторону, а это уже думаю вы сможете сделать самостоятельно.

Comment: Сделала подобное для ViewBox, то что нужно!!!

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128117/discussion-on-answer-by-evgeniyz----usercontrol-wpf).