# WPF Как сделать размер кнопки зависимым от размера окна?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net

У меня есть Button c такими параметрами: Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" (У окна есть Grid). Если я изменяю размер окна, то все кнопки так же изменяют размер. В чём собственно проблема? Я решил сделать анимацию кнопки и изменяю её Width уменьшая в 2 раза с помощью DoubleAnimation. Всё работает, но вот только после анимации (изменения Width кнопки) ширина кнопки перестаёт изменяться, если я изменяю размер окна, что не скажешь про высоту (Height изменяется в зависимости от размера окна). Можно ли как-то сделать анимацию изменения ширины кнопки, но после окончания анимации кнопка изменяла свои размеры в зависимости от размера окна? (Работаю с WPF не так давно, по-этому возможно делаю что-то неправильно. Если нужны фрагменты кода, то могу скинуть)

Comment: А можно [mcve]?

Comment: Мне кажется, вы хотите нечто [такое](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1217026/220553).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ: ага, RenderTransform — самый правильный вариант

Comment: @EvgeniyZ: Спасибо большое, я попробовал сделать что-то похожее через XAML, всё работает, но как это сделать в коде? Я пытался, делал DoubleAnimation и изменял ScaleTransform.ScaleXProperty, но как-то безуспешно

P.S. Не знаю как прикрепить фото к комментарию, по-этому прикрепил к вопросу

Comment: @Alkamal Забудьте про использование контролов в коде, это не WinForms. В WPF, с ее разметкой, системой привязок работа с контролами в коде очень плохо!

Comment: Большое спасибо! Буду знать

Comment: На будущее. Если вы хотите конкретный ответ с конкретным примером, вам нужно задать конкретный вопрос и показать рабочую XAML разметку и код. Сейчас лично мне непонятно примерно ничего, быть может потому что у меня не очень с воображением. Если бы вы показали разметку и не экономили на буквах (они кстати здесь бесплатные), то намного быстрее смогли бы получить нужный ответ. А так, ссылка выше на пример @EvgeniyZ, как мне кажется - то что нужно.

Answer (score 1):

Один из методов сделать такое — это анимировать не ширину кнопки, а множитель, который вначале имеет значение 1, и анимируется к значению 0.5. Сам множитель можно положить либо в `Tag`, либо в attached property, а ширину кнопки привязать к ширине ячейки (для этого на дно ячейки можно положить невидимый `Grid`) и множителю через умножающий `IMultiValueConverter` (который придётся написать вручную).