# C# WPF Поворот картинки относительно некоторой точки

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне повернуть картинку (в данном случае, стрелка) вокруг ее нижней (синей) точки, а не центра стрелки[image: Вокруг центра картинки]

[image: Вот так хотелось бы, но на скрине представление с печальнейшими марджинами]

```
<Ellipse
            Width="10"
            Height="10"
            Fill="Blue"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Margin="0,224,3.5,0"/>
        <Image Source="/Assets/ma.png" 
               Height="100" Width="300"
               VerticalAlignment="Top"
               Margin="0,55,0,0"/>
        <Image Source="/Assets/стрелка.png" 
                   Stretch="Uniform" 
                   Height="140" Width="14" 
                   StretchDirection="Both" 
                   VerticalAlignment="Top"
                   Margin="0,95,4,0"/>
```

Comment: Создать картинку со стрелкой, где кончик стрелки - левый верхний угол изображения { X = 0, Y = 0 } (или чуть дальше, но направлено в ту сторону), а точка опоры стрелки (середина синего круга) - центр изображения, например { X = 50, Y = 50 }, при размере изображения { H = 100, W = 100 } После этого - хоть завращайся....

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17553723/12888024

Comment: Я делал [такой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1217026/220553) ответ, где анимировал увеличение объекта, с поворотом будет примерно все тоже самое, за исключением того, что будет использован другой `RenderTransform` (а именно `RotateTransform`). Также там внимание обратите на `RenderTransformOrigin`, который и задает "централюную точку".