# Табло для вывода информации. Выбрать winform или wpf?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, form

Друзья здр! Немного запутался.
Необходимо сделать в местный Дом Пионеров программу для вывода информации. Табло для Самбо. Начал делать на winform но столкнулся с проблемой следующего характера (см. далее).
ТЗ (кратко): программа состоит из двух окон: панели управления и масштабируемого табло. Считаем в первом и выводим информацию во втором.

Что сделал: две формы, кнопка с первой открывает вторую и.....
Проблема: не могу передать int во вторую форму, требуется string, что не есть хорошо ибо хотел через кнопку "+" на первой форме считать очки. Нажимаем на плюсик, а на табло прибавляются очки.
Вывод сделал на label, но он не масштабируется по размеру окна, или я не допедрил как((

Прошу помочь советами)

Comment: Вопрос себе задайте, вам важна графика, визуальная составляющая? Если да, то WPF ваш выбор, а если нет, берите WinForms. Проблема последнего в том, что там за всю графику вы отвечаете сами, вы сами ее условно говоря рисуете, весь дизайн вашего приложения, там даже простая прозрачность может обернуться проблемами. Ну а WPF имеет совершенно другой подход в этом плане, у него даже весь дизайн вынесен в XAML, что позволяет многие графические вещи сделать без единой строки C# кода. Допустим вот [масштабирование на WPF](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1217026/220553). Как видите, выбор за вами.

Comment: Спасибо. Буду пробовать wpf.

Comment: Либо используйте контрол WebBrowser.

Comment: @XelaNimed `WebBrowser` это InternetExplorer 11, он устарел, умер и разложился. Если уж на то пошло, то есть `WebView2` (Edge), советую с ним познакомиться. Ну и использовать веб для десктопных приложений при таком обилии нативных решений - странный выбор. :)

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: @aepot Ну почемуж странный, наоборот, сейчас почти каждая крупная компания делает так, всякие мессенджеры по типу телеграмм, ватсап, дискорд, вк; магазины, например стим, ну и куча других - это все адаптивная веб морда, которая грузится у клиента, даже VS Code это веб) Правильней будет наверно сказать "через браузер такое делать странно", но а через какой нибудь Electron, вполне.